# Azure CosmosDB replace a row with a unique key

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Is there an easy way to overwrite a row that contains a unique index, rather than just failing?

Or do I need to do an update and/or a delete then add.

It would be nice to have a setting when trying to add a row that would violate a unique index constraint it would replace the exist row that matches that the unique index.

My db is defined on Azure using a Core (SQL) API. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UpsertItemAsync(). This will work.